# Can PHP 8 Enum be passed as function argument?

Tags: php

I have a Enum that implements a given interface:

```php
namespace App\Model;

use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatableInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

enum UserRole: string implements TranslatableInterface
{
    case User = 'ROLE_USER';
    case ZoneManager = 'ROLE_ZONE_MANAGER';
    case SuperAdmin = 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN';

    public function trans(TranslatorInterface $translator, ?string $locale = null): string
    {
        return match ($this) {
            self::User => $translator->trans('roles.user', locale: $locale),
            self::ZoneManager => $translator->trans('roles.zone_manager', locale: $locale),
            self::SuperAdmin => $translator->trans('roles.super_admin', locale: $locale),
        };
    }
}
```

I wrote a function to return an array of enum value (as string) and the corresponding translation:

```php
private function translateEnum(\BackedEnum&TranslatableInterface $enum)
{
    return array_combine(
        array_map(fn(\BackedEnum $v) => $v->value, $enum::cases()),
        array_map(
            fn(\BackedEnum&TranslatableInterface $v) => $v->trans($this->translator), 
            $enum::cases()),
    );
}
```

How can I pass `UserRole` enum to my function, an a "whole"? Of course `UserRole::class` won't work (is a string) neither `UserRole` alone works.

Comment: Surely you need to pass an _instance_ of an enum you've created? The _definition_ of the num isn't something you could pass around I don't think, just like you can't pass a regular class definition around (you'd have to pass an instance).

Comment: For the purpose you're interested in, might it not be easier to have the translateEnum function simply accept the array generated by calling the enum's cases() function? That's static, so you don't need an instance for that.

Comment: As you can see the translateEnum function use cases() to generally get all values from the enum (as string) and call trans on it, so yes... it's meant to be used as a generic function, don't want/need to pass an istance.

Comment: @ADyson sure, but you would loose the type hints!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using static analysis, both [Psalm](https://psalm.dev/) and [PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/) support the `class-string<T>` type annotation.

Define your function as follows:

```php
/**
 * @param class-string<BackedEnum&TranslatableInterface> $enumClass
 */
private function translateEnum(string $enumClass)
{
    return array_combine(
        array_map(fn(\BackedEnum $v) => $v->value, $enum::cases()),
        array_map(
            fn(TranslatableInterface $v) => $v->trans($this->translator), 
            $enumClass::cases()),
    );
}
```

Both Psalm and PHPStan will now complain if you pass a class string that does not implement `BackedEnum&TranslatableInterface`.

```php
interface TranslatableInterface {}

enum MyBackedEnum: string implements TranslatableInterface {}

enum NotABackedEnum {}

enum NotATranslatableEnum: string {}

translateEnum(MyBackedEnum::class); // Ok

translateEnum(NotABackedEnum::class); // Error

translateEnum(NotATranslatableEnum::class); // Also an error
```

See here for a playground example: https://phpstan.org/r/9e56fbe5-e8c7-4300-a32c-aad79976f47c.

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution but I’m not a big fan of these annotations (i love phpstan btw). I guess what I’asking is not possible so maybe i’ll use a trait for that